# Use partial fractions to find the integral.

Tags: calculus, partial-fractions

Find the integral using partial factions.

$$\int\frac{(2x^2+5x+3)}{(x-1)(x^2+4)}\,dx$$

So do I do...$$\frac{2x^2+5x+3}{(x-1)(x^2+4)}=\frac{A}{x-1} + \frac{Bx+C}{x^2+4},$$

then get 
\begin{align*}
2x^2+5x+3 &= A(x^2+4)+(Bx+C)(x-1) \\
2x^2+5x+3 &= Ax^2+4A+Bx^2-Bx+Cx-C?
\end{align*}

Comment: Welcome to MSE! What have you tried and where are you stuck? Regards

Comment: I'm stuck at multiplying by (x-1)(x^2-4) through A/(x-1) + Bx+/(x^2+4)... I get Ax^2-4A+Bx^2-Bx+Cx-C? Is that right?

Comment: @Itzel You should multiply by $(x - 1)(x^2 + 4)$, not $(x - 1)(x^2 - 4)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that we can simply add zero: $2x^2 = 2(x^2 + 4) - 8 = 2x^2 + 8 - 8$. Then
$$\frac{2x^2 + 5x + 3}{(x - 1)(x^2 + 4)} = \frac{2(x^2 + 4) - 8 + 5x + 3}{(x - 1)(x^2 + 4)} = \frac{2}{x - 1} + \frac{5x - 5}{(x - 1)(x^2 + 4)}.$$
Do you think you can integrate
$$\frac{2x^2 + 5x + 3}{(x - 1)(x^2 + 4)}$$
now?

Hint:
$$\frac{5x - 5}{(x - 1)(x^2 + 4)} = \frac{5(x - 1)}{(x - 1)(x^2 + 4)} = \frac{5}{x^2 + 4}$$
and
$$\int \frac{1}{x^2 + a^2} = \frac{1}{a}\tan^{-1}\frac{x}{a} + C, \quad a \ne 0.$$

Comment: Where did you get 5x-5?

Comment: Note: $5x - 8 + 3 = 5x - 5$ and $(A + B)/C = A/C + B/C$.

Comment: To expect the typical student to come up with such "notes" is ludicrous. Maybe you can do polynomial division/partial fractions in your head, but most students cannot...

Comment: What? There is no polynomial division here, I simply added zero: $2x^2 = 2(x^2 + 4) - 8 = 2x^2 + 8 - 8$. This is Algebra I. Please read before you downvote my answer for no reason.

Comment: Sorry I didn't mean to down vote your answer. I don't even think I can or it wasn't me.

Comment: @Itzel No, not you. I think it was The Chaz 2.0. Feel free to upvote my answer if you find it helpful.

Comment: @anyone please check my edit I added.

Comment: @Itzel Yes, but my method is much simpler (I think).

Comment: @TheChaz2.0 Do you see something I do not?

Comment: I bet it is but that's just how we are learning it right now and I need to get it down. Thank you though.

Comment: Hey @glebovg I'm stuck at what to plug in for x to get my A,B,C and ideas?

Comment: I fully understand what you did. The way that this is presented is more like guessing than following a method. OP asked for the method of partial fractions, not magically coming up with a clever version of zero to add... Anywho. OP, try $x=1$.

Comment: @TheChaz2.0 There is no magic here, I merely used the fact that $x^2 + 4$ is in the denominator. Never mind.

Comment: @Itzel Obviously setting $x = 1$ yields $A = 10$. Now simply choose some other convenient values of $x$, $x = 2$ and $x = 3$, say, and solve a system of equations.

Comment: @TheChaz2.0 is that right?

Comment: How is A=10 I keep getting 10/-3=A?

Comment: @Itzel Yes, sorry. It should be $A = 10/5 = 2$. It was a typo.

Comment: @Itzel How are getting $A = -10/3$? Since $2x^2 + 5x + 3 = A(x^2 + 4) + (Bx + C)(x - 1)$, we set $x = 1$ and obtain $2 + 5 + 3 = 5A$, so $A = 2$.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are stuck at the actual *partial fraction decomposition*, rather than at the integration. So let's pick up at $$2x^2+5x+3= A(x^2+4) + (Bx+C)(x-1)$$

While this must hold true for all values of $x$, certain values of $x$ will lead us to the values of $A,B,C$ more quickly...

$x = 1$ is a natural choice, as that will make the $(Bx+C)$ go away. We then have $$2(1)^2 + 3(1) + 5 = A((1)^2 + 4) + 0$$
$$2 + 3 + 5 = 5A$$
$$A=2$$

Then you could use complex x-values ($\pm 2i$ for example) and equate real and imaginary parts, but you could just pick a few other small (real) x-values for ease of computation.

So $x=2$ gives us $21 = 16 + 2B + C$, or $$2B +C = 5$$

Then $x = 3$ gives us $36 = 26 + (3B+C)(2)$, or $$3B+C = 5$$

Solving these last two equations simultaneously gives $B = 0, C = 5$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Write out the fraction given as $\frac{A}{x-1}+\frac{Bx+C}{x^2+4}$ and equate the numerator to $2x^2+5x+3$. And the ensuing integral should be easy.

Comment: Hi can you help me out?